# How To Use ValueConverter as StaticResource in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, ivalueconverter, valueconverter

Below is my App.xaml

```
<Application
    x:Class="SpinrWindowsMobile.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    >

    <!--Application Resources-->
    <Application.Resources >
        <ResourceDictionary>

            <local:LocalizedStrings xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SpinrWindowsMobile" x:Key="LocalizedStrings"/>
            <converter:TextColorConverter xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:SpinrWindowsMobile.Common" x:Key="TextColorConverter"></converter:TextColorConverter>

        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>

    ....
</Application>
```

I had written **TextColorConverter.cs** in NameSpace **SpinrWindowsMobile.Common**
While launching the app It gives me exception **can not create Instance of Type SpinrWindowsMobile.Common.TextColorConverter** . I don't know where am I missing.
Below is the my **TextColorConverter.cs** class

```
class TextColorConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            // some code
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
           // some code
        }
    }
```

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 For Windows Phone as My Development Tool.
One more thing I want to share I am not getting **ValueConverstionAttribute Class** in **System.Windows.Data** namespace.
Can anyone guide me where am I wrong.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You will make your class a public class (by default it will be internal). Otherwise it can't be instantiated.

*public* class TextColorConverter : IValueConverter